# QGraphicsView: how to make rubber band selection appear only on left mouse button?

Tags: qt, pyqt, qt5, qgraphicsview, qgraphicsscene

I want to make a `QGraphicsScene` and show it in `QGraphicsView`. I want to scroll the scene by middle mouse button and make rubber band selection by left button. But I don't know how to make the rubber band selection appear only by left mouse button.

Here's my code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import os, sys

from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui, QtSvg

class MegaSceneView(QtWidgets.QGraphicsView):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MegaSceneView, self).__init__(parent)
        self._scale_factor = 1.0

        self._scale_by = 1.2
        self.setAcceptDrops(True)

        self.setRenderHint(QtGui.QPainter.Antialiasing)
        self.setMouseTracking(True)
        self.setRubberBandSelectionMode(QtCore.Qt.IntersectsItemShape)
        self.setDragMode(QtWidgets.QGraphicsView.RubberBandDrag)

        self._prev_mouse_scene_pos = None


    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        if (event.buttons() & QtCore.Qt.MidButton) != QtCore.Qt.NoButton:
            self._prev_mouse_scene_pos = (event.pos())
        super(MegaSceneView, self).mousePressEvent(event)

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        super(MegaSceneView, self).mouseReleaseEvent(event)
        self._prev_mouse_scene_pos = None

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        super(MegaSceneView, self).mouseMoveEvent(event)

        if (event.buttons() & QtCore.Qt.MidButton) != QtCore.Qt.NoButton:
            cur_mouse_pos = (event.pos())
            if self._prev_mouse_scene_pos is not None:
                delta_x = cur_mouse_pos.x() - self._prev_mouse_scene_pos.x()
                delta_y = cur_mouse_pos.y() - self._prev_mouse_scene_pos.y()

                self.horizontalScrollBar().setValue(self.horizontalScrollBar().value() - delta_x)
                self.verticalScrollBar().setValue(self.verticalScrollBar().value() - delta_y)

            self._prev_mouse_scene_pos = (event.pos())

if __name__ == "__main__":

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    mega_view = MegaSceneView()

    mega_scene = QtWidgets.QGraphicsScene(-500, -500, 1000, 1000)
    # mega_scene = QtWidgets.QGraphicsScene()

    rect_item_1 = QtWidgets.QGraphicsRectItem(-30, -20, 60, 40)
    mega_scene.addItem(rect_item_1)

    rect_item_2 = QtWidgets.QGraphicsRectItem(-20, -30, 40, 60)
    mega_scene.addItem(rect_item_2)
    rect_item_2.setPos(300, 200)

    mega_view.setScene(mega_scene)
    mega_view.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

What should I add to make the rubber band appear only by left button?

Answer (score 5):

You can set the drag mode in the `mousePressEvent` and  `mouseReleaseEvent` functions in your view class, so it stays in the `RubberBandDrag` as default, but switches to `NoDrag` mode when the middle mouse button is held.

Like so - c++, but the idea is the same in all languages - :

```
void YourViewClass::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent* event)    {
    if (event->buttons() == Qt::MiddleButton)
        setDragMode(QGraphicsView::NoDrag);
}

void YourViewClass::mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent* event)    {
    if (event->button() == Qt::MiddleButton)
        setDragMode(QGraphicsView::RubberBandDrag);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

There isn't a built-in way to do this. You will need to subclass the `mousePressEvent`, `mouseMoveEvent`, and `mouseReleaseEvent` for your graphics view and create the visible rubber band yourself. (`QRubberBand` works well for this.) When the user releases the mouse, you then need to convert the rubber band extents into scene coordinates and call `QGraphicsScene::setSelectionArea`.